# Nebular theme and raw HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, innerhtml, nebular

I use 2 nebular themes: light and dark.
A component bind the HTML result from a library to the innerHtml like this:

```html
<div [innerHtml]="songHtml"></div>
```

I apply custom css to style this content. To make it work, I added

```js
@Component({
    [...]
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
```

Now I need to apply theme color like this:

```css
@include nb-install-component() {
    .chords-color-red {
        color: nb-theme(text-color-red)
    }
}
```

but this is not working... I read that this cannot work with the ViewEncapsulation.

What I also tried (without success):

- ::ng-deep .nb-theme-dark
- safeHtml pipe (with sanitizer) and removing ViewEncapsulation

Is there a way to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something but it's not pretty.

1. I removed the ViewEncapsulation
2. I put every css that I want to apply to the innerHTML in ::ng-deep { }
3. point 2) does not work with nb-install-component so I put every nb-theme outside of the ::ng-deep { } and added ::ng-deep in front of each css group

Note: ng-deep is deprecated but I found no other way to make it work